# Getting stack trace from Perl "Out of memory" error

Tags: perl, memory, out-of-memory

tl;dr: How to dump a perl stack trace when a Perl httpd process runs out of memory.

We've got a mod_perl 2 server, Perl 5.8.8, RHEL 5.6, Linux 2.6.18.

Very occasionally and unpredictably, a child httpd process starts using up all available memory at an alarming rate. We've at least used BSD::Resource::setrlimit(RLIMIT_VMEM, ...), so that the process dies with "Out of memory" before bringing down the server.

We don't know where in the code this is happening, and it's difficult to reproduce without hours of load testing.

What we'd really like is a way to get a **Perl stack trace** just before the process runs out of memory, so we know what code is causing this. Unfortunately, "Out of memory" is an [untrappable error](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html).

Here are the options I'm considering, each with their drawbacks:

1) Use the [$^M emergency memory pool](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). Requires us to recompile perl with -DPERL_EMERGENCY_SBRK and -Dusemymalloc.

2) Put in tons of log statements, then analyze the logs to see where the process is stopping short.

3) Write an external script that constantly scans the pool of httpd processes, and if it sees one using a lot of memory, sends it a USR2 signal (which we've arranged to dump a stack trace).

4) Somehow have the process monitor its own memory continuously, and dump a stack trace when memory gets high but before the "Out of Memory" error.

Thanks!

Jon

Comment: Is it possible to run the process under [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::NYTProf)?

Comment: Like I said, the problem happens very rarely - let's say after an hour of load testing - so we'd have to collect a massive amount of data if we ran under profiling or under heavy logging.Also it would be nice to have a solution that would work in production, where obviously we can't run under Devel::NYTProf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using LD_PRELOAD to load a custom version of malloc/free.  It should not be necessary to relink or recompile anything.  Just set LD_PRELOAD to have a .so that has the same interface as malloc, and this preloaded version of malloc will be loaded instead of the normal system malloc when you run your executable. For instance, this is a common strategy for detecting memory errors with [efence](http://linux.die.net/man/3/efence).

I don't think efence will work for you here as that is for detecting memory overwrites, not debugging out of memory (I don't know what it does on OOM).  I think what you might want to check out [failmalloc](http://www.nongnu.org/failmalloc/). I have never used this one but it sounds like it might do what you want (I only skimmed the front page).

Comment: Interesting. So theoretically I could create a malloc hook (http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) that calls malloc, and if an OOM occurs,

1) raise the soft VMEM limit

2) re-call malloc with the same arguments (which should now succeed with the higher limit)

3) get the process to dump a Perl stack trace (e.g. by sending itself a SIGUSR2)

Answer (score 3):

You can get a backtrace with `mod_backtrace`, see [Andy Millar's introduction](http://www.andymillar.co.uk/blog/2009/10/22/debugging-apache-child-segmentation-faults-using-mod_whatkilledus-and-mod_backtrace/). The backtrace is on the C level, so you either need

- a bit of Perl internals knowledge to infer the Perl stack by simply looking at the backtrace or
- to run gdb, set a breakpoint at the crashy function and examine the Perl stack and lexical variables with the gdb macros from the mod_perl book.

Comment: Thanks. Is there really enough information in a C-level backtrace to determine where we are in the Perl stack, not just the line of code we were at but the callers etc?

Comment: Jonathan: There is, somewhere, but it's not necessarily easy or public. You could use call_sv/etc (see perlcall) to call back into Perl to do a Carp::cluck of your memory constraints allow for that.

Answer (score 0):

According to *Practical mod_perl*, adding `Apache::Debug level => 4;` to your code  will cause it to allocate the $^M emergency pool and call `Carp::confess()`.

https://books.google.co.vi/books?id=i3Ww_7a2Ff4C&pg=PT699&lpg=PT699&dq=how+do+i+get+a+stack+trace+when+perl+dies+with+an+out+of+memory+error&source=bl&ots=Id7ll9Gng2&sig=r8SpZ4jvFfjzfM2eSmoV2DjWLnY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwqNitporbAhXow1kKHZo9CRoQ6AEIODAC#v=onepage&q=how%20do%20i%20get%20a%20stack%20trace%20when%20perl%20dies%20with%20an%20out%20of%20memory%20error&f=false