# Efficiently monitoring httpd children and signalling those using too much memory/cpu

Tags: perl, apache, monitoring, mod-perl

We use Apache/mod_perl 2 and occasionally get a child httpd process that spins out of control, either consuming ever-increasing amounts of memory or max cpu.

I would like to monitor for such children every second or so, and when finding one, send it a USR2 signal so it can dump its current Perl stack to our error logs.

(Note that we are using rlimit/BSD::Resource, but when a process exceeds its memory rlimit, it dies immediately with no good way to log or take action (see [Getting stack trace from Perl "Out of memory" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348158)). So AFAICT rlimit will have to be complemented by an external monitoring program.)

I see that [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is highly regarded, but I can't figure out any way to monitor and send a signal to an individual httpd process. It seems geared towards killing or restarting services like apache as a whole. Am I missing something?

If I have to write a Perl script that does this, is there anything that will efficiently monitor the process table? [Proc::ProcessTable](https://metacpan.org/release/Proc-ProcessTable) takes .02 secs of cpu to generate a single table, so running that every second seems unnecessarily expensive. Opening up a "/usr/bin/top -b -d 1 |" and parsing the results is my current best idea.

Obviously would rather not badly reinvent a wheel if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [control groups](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cgroups.txt) to quickly get a list of processes associated with apache, and focus your attention there. Simply put the main apache process into a control group prior to it spawning any child processes (eg, you could have a launcher process add itself to a control group), then read off the tasks file in the cgroup virtual directory. For each PID there, examine its CPU usage via the normal /proc mechanisms.